# No parameterless constructor defined for this object while posting data with jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following jquery that should post data and register a band:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById("CoverPicture").files[0];
formData.append("file", file);
var Name = $('#Name').val();
var Genre = $('#Genre').val();
var CoverPicture = formData;
var BandDescription = $('#Description').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:65148/Home/BandRegister',
        data: {
            'name': Name,
            'genre': Genre,
            'coverPicture': CoverPicture,
            'description': BandDescription
        },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult BandRegister(string name, string genre, HttpFileCollection coverPicture, string description)
{
    var file = Request.Files;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("SetupNewProfile");
    }
```

}

When I run this, I get this error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

And problem Is the `HttpFileCollection`. How can post data AND upload image at the same time with jquery in asp.net? How can I solve my problem here?

Comment: You can't have formData as a value inside an object, you have to post the formData as the **only** data, but you can append both strings and files to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `FormData` you need to use it for all data sent by appending key/values

Change

```
formData.append("file", file);
var Name = $('#Name').val();
var Genre = $('#Genre').val();
var CoverPicture = formData;
var BandDescription = $('#Description').val();
```

To

```
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("Name ",$('#Name').val());
formData.append("Genre",$('#Genre').val());
....etc
```

Then for data property in `$.ajax` config:

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    data:formData,
    ....
});
```